# iCarousel is not working in custom TableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

First of All Thanks for the iCarousel. I am trying the iCarousel in custom TableView Cell, but it crashes by saying "Unrecognized selector sent in numberOfItemsInCarousel". Please help me on this. Thanks in advance..!

```
-(nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TimelineCell *cell = (TimelineCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"timelineCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *cellItem = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TimelineCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [cellItem firstObject];
    }
    cell.images = imageArray;
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    [carousel setType:iCarouselTypeTimeMachine];
    return [_images count];
}
```

Comment: Are both the methods you've provided above implemented in the same class?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the delegate for the iCarousel is set to something else than the class implementing the method `numberOfItemsInCarousel:(…`.

Make sure you've set the delegate to the correct instance.

You probably want the `TimelineCell` to be the carousel delegate, so make sure that you do set it (either in your xib-file or programatically). Put the `numberOfItemsInCarousel(…`-method implementation in the `TimelineCell` class and it should work.

Another tip is to not set the carousel type in the method `numberOfItemsInCarousel(…`. Not a pretty place for it. Instead do it in some initialisation method.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have set iCarousel delegate and datasource in UITableViewCell and implemented there.. And _images is an array of images to display in iCarousel.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint somewhere so that you can inspect the value of carousel.delegate in the cell

Comment: Yeah tried, but it is not getting inside UITableViewCell class. Before itself it crashes